# R plotting dates with apcluster

Tags: r, matrix, plot, cluster-analysis

I'm using the package `apcluster` to do some clustering on some data. I currently have a large matrix called `mat` which follows this format:

```
             date          A             B            C
1      2000-01-03  2.00000000  0.300000000   4.00000000
2      2000-01-04  0.20000000  0.000030000  -0.02469136
3      2000-01-05 -0.07692308  -0.02469136  -0.07594937
```

`apcluster` has provided functionality to plot the clusters (as scatterboxes) overlaid on your original data. When plotting I do:

```
plot(cluster, mat)
```

Don't need to worry about `cluster`, only `mat` is giving me problems. The above gives me 9 plots... The diagonals being the column names (except date) and each plot representing the data of each column plotted against another. This means that the `X` and `Y` axes are in the range of the data ie. for `A`, it would be from `-0.08` to `2.0`!

So my question is how can I plot each column to date, as in date will act as the `X` axis, while the data from `mat` acts as `Y` **and** so that all three columns of data will appear on **one** plot, without modifying the `plot` command above?

`apcluster` documentation is located [HERE](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/apcluster/apcluster.pdf).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you need. Do you want to include the date column into both the clustering procedure and the plot? If you run apcluster() on the data frame you mention above, the date column is simply neglected.

So, if you want to include the date column, my suggestion would be to convert the date column to numeric, e.g. by the following:

```
    x$date <- as.numeric(as.Date(x$date))
```

The disadvantage is that the result is in days (from 1970-01-01), so (1) the column would be on a completely different scale than the other columns and (2) the axes of the plots would not be labeled in a very interpretable way. So it is probably better to convert the dates to fractions of years, e.g. something like 2013-01-01 = 2013.00; 2013-07-01 ~= 2013.50; 2014-01-01 = 2014.00. Do you know what I mean?

If you choose any of these two options, the dates will be taken into account by apcluster() and the plot() command will also plot the columns A, B, ... against the date column.

Cheers,
UBod

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is essentially what I have implemented haha.